# Google sheets nested if statement workaround

Tags: google-sheets

Link to [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fl7VSvU9S1CEA5eY6O8IHyzyv_TV8B3awmPKQx7TOz4/edit?usp=sharing):

I'm trying to make a scorecard and leaderboard for my golf team, and I need to calculate how many holes a person has finished. The nested if statement in cell J2

```
=if(G11, 18, 
  =if(G10, 17, 
  =if(G9, 16, 
  =if(G8, 15, 
  =if(G7, 14, 
  =if(G6, 13, 
  =if(G5, 12, 
  =if(G4, 11, 
  =if(G3, 10, 
  =if(C11, 9,  
  =if(C10, 8, 
  =if(C9, 7, 
  =if(C8, 6, 
  =if(C7, 5, 
  =if(C6, 4, 
  =if(C5, 3, 
  =if(C4, 2, 
  =if(C3, 1, 0))))))))))))))))))
```

should accomplish what I need but there are too many functions in the cell to work.

The current function checks the cell where the 18th hole score should be, and if it's there, the player is through 18 holes. If not, it goes to the first nested if and checks the 17th hole score cell, etc...

I know I could do part the function in three different cells and it would work fine, but I'm curious if anyone has any better ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
 `=IF(G7,14,IF(G6,13,IF(G5,12,IF(G4,11,IF(G3,10,IF(C11,9,IF(C10,8,IF(C9,7,IF(C8,6,IF(C7,5,IF(C6,4,IF(C5,3,IF(C4,2,IF(C3,1,0))))))))))))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to calculate ***how many*** holes a person has finished.

I believe what you need is the `COUNT` function.

```
 =COUNT({G3:G11;C3:C11})
```

This will give the total number of holes a person has finished.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there would be an easy way to do it, I just haven't worked with excel functions too much and didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 0):

Below returns an array of all the hole numbers  in the first set that has a value against it

```
=ArrayFormula(E3:E11*(G3:G11<>""))
```

Below returns the maximum of the hole numbers among all the holes that have a value against them.

```
=MAX(ArrayFormula(E3:E11*(G3:G11<>"")),ArrayFormula(A3:A11*(C3:C11<>"")))
```

Broke it up for brevity, but the second one is what I guess you need.